# Nextjs project is not hot reloading in MacOs

Tags: macos, next.js, hot-reload

Well, i try searching a solution but i cant find anything.

A coworker passed me project in NextJs (With React of course).   I run yarn install, and then yarn run dev,  the server starts but when i made a change in the code,  it is not hot reloading!  I have to stop and start the server manually each time.

I tried sudo yarn run dev,  i tried with npm,  y tried a lot of things.

I dont know much about MacOs, i just bought this days ago... The project work perfect on my Windows machine.

This are my current node and yarn version on mac
devmcgann@MacBook-Pro-de-Gabriel instashop-webapp % node --version
v12.16.1
devmcgann@MacBook-Pro-de-Gabriel instashop-webapp % yarn --version
1.22.4

Edit: I tried making a simple react app and hot reload work perfect there. 
But with nextJS the problem persists

Thanks!

Answer (score -5, accepted):

Well.. This is rare.
Yarnd install and also npm install.   I didnt now that i will need both. 
Fixed.

Comment: Having both yarn and npm is never recommended.

Answer (score 12):

I had similar issues. The problem was the incorrect imports.

Some of my files and folder were in lowercase but in imports I was using uppercase.

Even though the build is successfully done without error, the hot reload doesn't work. So I had to correct them in order to make them work.

Comment: This happened to me last week and now it's happening again but I can't find this import issue this time :/

Comment: I know it is bit tough and TBH I don't know if there is any better way to debug but try commenting out your each recently worked components.

Comment: You cannot believe how grateful I am. Finally, it's working again

Answer (score 1):

- Make sure your routes case matches the case of the folder.
- Make sure the component name has to start with the upper case. If your file name is dashboard.jsx, the component name should be Dashboard.

```
// home/dashboard.js
    
const Dashboard = () => {
    
    ....
    
}
export default Dashboard
```